# Need to verify a firebaseapp.com subdomain

Tags: dns, domain, google-search

In order to use Firebase Authentication properly with my project, I have to verify the ownership of a firebaseapp.com subdomain (linked to my project by default) in the Google Search Console. Therefore Google wants me to add a DNS record to this domain. Unfortunately I can not find an option for this in my firebase project settings. 
Does anyone know, how I can do this? 
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, do you find a solution? I'm facing the same issue now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've got verified today and here's what I did.

I just requested a review without doing anything for firebaseapp.com subdomain. And once they asked me to verify my ownership of the domain, just explained that the domain is auto-created by Firebase, and I can't modify its DNS record, and finally I asked if there is anything we can do to workaround.

Then they suddenly verified my oAuth consent screen.

Comment: Okay thanks for the advise. I will try it as well.

Comment: Hi there, can I ask how you were able to explain the situation to google? Through email? Or a support channel?

Comment: Hi, I just responded to the inquiry from Google. They send an inquiry via email when you request a review and find anything that doesn't meet their requirements.